# Docker PostgreSQL 9.6 - installing extension plpython3u (clashing with quantile extension)

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am trying to install a PostgreSQL dockerised service, with plpython. I am able to build the image successfully, but when I come to run the container, I get the following error:

> ERROR:  could not open extension control file
>   "/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/extension/plpython3u.control": No such file
>   or directory STATEMENT:  CREATE EXTENSION "plpython3u";
>   psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_db.sql:7: ERROR:  could not
>   open extension control file
>   "/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/extension/plpython3u.control": No such file
>   or directory

#### my directory layout:

```
me@yourbox:~/Projects/experimental/docker/scratchdb$ tree
.
├── Dockerfile
└── sql
    ├── create_db.sql
    └── schemas
        └── DDL
            └── db_schema_foo.sql
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM library/postgres:9.6
FROM zitsen/postgres-pgxn

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    python3 postgresql-plpython3-9.6

RUN pgxn install quantile

COPY sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ 

# Add VOLUMEs to allow backup of config, logs and databases
VOLUME  ["/etc/postgresql", "/var/log/postgresql", "/var/lib/postgresql"]

# Set the default command to run when starting the container
# CMD ["/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/postgres", "-D", "/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf"]
```

#### create_db.sql

```
# Uncomment line below for debugging purposes
set client_min_messages TO debug1;

CREATE EXTENSION "quantile"
CREATE EXTENSION "plpython3u";

-- Create myappuser
CREATE ROLE myappuser LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'passw0rd123' NOINHERIT;
CREATE DATABASE only_foo_and_horses WITH ENCODING 'UTF8' TEMPLATE template1;
-- \l+
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE only_foo_and_horses TO myappuser;

-- Import only_foo_and_horses DDL and initialise database data
\c only_foo_and_horses;
\i /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schemas/DDL/db_schema_foo.sql;



-- # enable python in database
```

**[[Edit]]**

These are the commands I use to build and run the container:

```
docker build -t scratch:pg .
docker run -it -rm scratch:pg
```

How do I install plpython in a dockerised PostgreSQL service?

Comment: At first glance, it looks like a version mix-up: `FROM library/postgres:9.6` vs `/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/` (note the 9.5 <-> 9.6)

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Yes I noticed that too. But modifiying the paths doesn't seem to do the trick, and at one point I used the PostgreSQL 9.5 image in my Dockerfile - error persisted through all of those changes - so I'm guessing it must be something different.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

I think your error was because of the initial erroneous `CMD` which pointed to the wrong location of PostgreSQL for this image (9.5 vs 9.6).

However, I think I've spotted the mistake for why the SQL isn't being imported.

The default `ENTRYPOINT` for this image (at https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/bef8f02d1fe2bb4547280ba609f19abd20230180/9.6/docker-entrypoint.sh) is responsible for importing from `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`. Since you are overwriting `CMD` and it is not equal to just `postgresql`, it is skipping this part.

The default `ENTRYPOINT` should do what you want. Try removing your `CMD`.

Comment: I think you may be mis-understanding the problem. The problem isn't that the SQL script isn't being imported (it is). It is that it fails when creating/installing the plpython language via the `CREATE EXTENSION` statement (which is in the imported SQL file).

Comment: Yes, i see. But can you update your error message? As it currently stands, it looks like the error is the wrong version folder destination.

Comment: Actually, I'm going to stick with my original answer. I've tested this myself and it does work. So, my guess is your `docker run` command is overwriting something (like the user) and causing an error. Can you please update your original question with the `docker run` command you are using?

Comment: it seems that in my attempt to preesent a simple replicable case, I had left out some relevant information in my `Dockerfile` and `create_database.sql` script. The issue is that attempting to install `plpython` fails when the `quantile` extension is also being installed. I have added the relevant details to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have just run this all from scratch and seems extension have been successfully created. Is there still an issue ?

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_db.sql
SET
CREATE EXTENSION
CREATE ROLE
CREATE DATABASE
GRANT


LOG:  received fast shutdown request
waiting for server to shut down...LOG:  aborting any active transactions
LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
LOG:  shutting down
.LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped

PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
```

Comment: it seems that in my attempt to preesent a simple replicable case, I had left out some relevant information in my `Dockerfile` and `create_database.sql` script. The issue is that attempting to install `plpython` fails when the `quantile` extension is also being installed. I have clarified my question.